# Post to Facebook Page Wall without logged in user

Tags: php, facebook

I have a Facebook app that I want to use to post on my customer's Facebook Page Walls on their behalf. I have it setup now so that when they authenticate my app I get the Access token, but when I go to post to the wall I am getting the following error: "OAuthException: Error validating access token: The session is invalid because the user logged out."

How can I post from my script without being logged in?

Here is my code:

```
include_once('fb-php-sdk/src/facebook.php');
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => 'XXX',
    'secret' => 'XXX',
));
try {
    $page_id = '215133535279290'; //page id of the customer's facebook page
    $args = array(
        'access_token' => 'XXX', //access token received when user authenticated app
        'message'      => 'A test message'
    );
    $post_id = $facebook->api("/$page_id/feed","post",$args);
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
echo "Error:" . $e;
}
```

Comment: You need to ask for offline permissions when getting the token

Comment: @Ashley https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Answer (score 0):

The new facebook API has what is called an extended access token (it replaces offline access: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/ I think) which I believe lasts upto 60 days (or something like that). To use it simply get the access token when the logs in through your website:

```
$token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
```

Save it to Db and use this token later:

```
$facebook = new Facebook();
$facebook->setAccessToken($accessTokenFromDB);
```

Then you should be able to continue as though the user is logged in.

As for the user being logged out part, make sure you are using the latest version of the API and not an old version and also make sure the stuff under the "Scenario 2: If you have been previously requesting offline_access - updated 4/30/2012" heading of the page I linked.

You could carry on using `offline_access` until 3rd of October, but then why if it's being turned off for real in 2 months time and would have to rewrite your code.

Answer (score 0):

Get the `publish_stream` extended permission.  Once you have this permission you can post feed  stories using your app access token while the user is offline.  There is no need for `offline_access` permissions or saving and using a user access token in this scenario.

Comment: AFAIK the owner of the page needs to grant this access (publish_stream) to the App first, before the App can post offline. That's what the access token is for. offline_access is highly deprecated and not necessary at all. Look in to the docs, there are several ways to refresh an expired `long living access_token` (60 days).